# Convert each value of the column from str to list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset in which the third column values are of type str like here

```
data.column_3[0]
>>>[['dog',1]]

type(data.column_3[0])
>>>str
```

I want to convert **each column's value** into the list.

I tried using to_list() but it inserts the str into a list and I get

```
data[column_3].to_list()
```

but this gives `['[','[','d','o','g','1',']',']']` and coverts complete series into list

I want to access `list[0] = 'dog' and list[1] = 1`

EDIT with sample:

```
 {0: "[['dog', 1]]",
 1: "[['cat', 1]]",
 2: "[['t1', 1]]",
 3: "[['t2', 1]]",
 4: "[['t3', 1]]",
 5: "[['t4', 1]]"}
```

Comment: can you post the output of `data['column_3'].head(5).to_dict()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': pd.Series({0: "[['dog', 1]]", 1: "[['cat', 1]]", 2: "[['t1', 1]]", 3: "[['t2', 1]]", 4: "[['t3', 1]]", 5: "[['t4', 1]]"})})
```

If your list is actually a **string representation of a list** you can use: `ast.liter_eval` to change the type to a real list:

```
import ast

df['col'] = df['col'].map(ast.literal_eval)
```

You can access it via `.str`

```
df['col'].str[0]

Out[5]: 
0    dog
1    cat
Name: col, dtype: object


df['col'].str[1]

Out[6]: 
0    1
1    2
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

---

to get the list per index in the lists:

```
df['col'].str[0].tolist()
# Out[7]: ['dog', 'cat']

df['col'].str[1].tolist()
# Out[8]: [1, 2]
```

---

to get a cumulated list:

```
df['col'].cumsum().iloc[-1]
# Out[13]: ['dog', 1, 'cat', 2]
```

Comment: Thnx! But `df['col'].str[0]` gives `[` from [['dog',1]] as the column value type is str.

Comment: @RaghaviR, thanks for the feedback, could you execute the following: `data[['column_3']].iloc[:5].to_dict()` and then post the result in you question? It should give us the 5 top entries in your coloumn as sample data.